# In C based - Sorting matrix 10x10 of random integers only on the third colomn

Tags: c, sorting

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    srand(time(NULL));
    fp = fopen ("dosyalar.txt", "w");
    int m, n;

    for(m = 0; m<10; m++) {
        for(n=0; n<10; n++) {
            fprintf(fp, " %d ", rand()%10000+1);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, when I compiled this code in terminal by typing `clang text.c -o test` and  `./test` and then `cat dosyalar.txt` . It gives me  10x10 matrix of random integers (0 - 10000). What I want is, **only third colomn** of random integers as sorted. How can I do this?

Comment: How can I do this only on third colomn?

Comment: I do this on terminal 'sort -u -k3' by doing this by I could not do this in code.

Comment: Do you know how the standard library function `qsort` works?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way: leave it as is and use

```
sort -k 3 dosyalar.txt
```

The other way:

Use an array and `qsort`, something like

```
int arr[10][10];

/* Fill array with some random numbers */

qsort(arr, 10, sizeof arr[0], compare);

int compare(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const int (*a)[10] = (const int (*)[10])pa;
    const int (*b)[10] = (const int (*)[10])pb;

    return a[3] - b[3];
}
```